# MS Access IIf statement with multiple conditions

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error, iif

I am trying to use an IIf statement in ms access 2000. I've searched around but have found nothing that accurately describes my situation. The current issue is when I try to use an IIf statement to output an answer dependent upon two parts or variables, it gives me a message stating that my syntax is incorrect. The line of code in question is as follows:

=IIf([Sold]=Yes, And IIF([Paid]=No, Then,"Not Paid"))

It gives me a message saying that my syntax is incorrect but upon removing the comma after the "Yes", it tells me that I've made too few arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of nested [`IIf()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) statements, but you only need the standard syntax:

```
IIf ( expr , truepart , falsepart )
```

`expr` is `[Sold]=Yes And [Paid]=No`. And there is no `Then` in IIf.

So your code should be:

```
=IIf([Sold]=Yes And [Paid]=No, "Not Paid", "Paid!")
```

or with a more common way to formulate the bool expression, and an empty `falsepart`:

```
=IIf([Sold] And Not [Paid], "Not paid", "")
```